# How to use output from an action as an expression in a if-condition for a Github Action workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I am building an workflow where an action provides a condition for a step in the workflow. How can I use this value?

The value from the action is blank and therefore evaluates to false and nothing is ever deployed...

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - id: verify
        name: verify if artifact is eligable for deployment
        uses: my.org/my.action.group/my.action.path@my.branch
      - name: release candidate
        run: echo release candidate - "${{ steps.verify.is-release-candidate }}"
      - name: deploy
        run: ...
        if: steps.verify.is-release-candidate
```

debug release candidate:

```
Run echo release candidate - ""
release candidate -
```

action.yml:

```
....
outputs:
  is-release-candidate:
    description: true if this new version can be auto deployed, false if not
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, except one small detail - you skipped `outputs` part when trying to access `is-release-candidate` -- correct version: `steps.<id>.outputs.<name>`.

```
- name: release candidate
  run:  echo "release candidate - ${{ steps.verify.outputs.is-release-candidate }}"
- name: deploy
  run:  ...
  if:   steps.verify.outputs.is-release-candidate
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this . you will get the output in the `find_output` variable and use that in the next step.

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:
      - id: verify
        name: verify if artifact is eligable for deployment
        uses: my.org/my.action.group/my.action.path@my.branch
        register : find_output
      - debug:
        var: find_output
      - name: deploy
        if: find_output.<use the key to validate>, yaml: A SEQUENCE WAS EXPECTED...
```

Comment: I'd like to see "register", "debug" and "yaml" explained unless they are artifacts from an earlier incarnation of github workflow syntax.